# Why does $\int_0^\infty \cos x^2 dx$ converge?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

I'm a B.C. student. I took a test and a question was:

> does $\int_0^\infty \cos x^2 dx$ converge?
>
> - Yes
> - No

I undoubtedly answered **No** because this is going to be somehow periodically, not exactly periodically but after any given number, there is a greater number $s$ that $\int_0^s \cos x^2 dx = 0$ and a little bit after $s$ the value is not zero. because it is ***$\cos$*** you know!

But after the test, I found out that the right answer is **Yes** and I was wrong.

Now I'm thinking for hours and I really really can't understand it. please help.

Comment: related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral#Properties

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use some elementary methods to prove this integral converges, consider that $$\int_0^\infty \cos(x^2)\,dx=\int_0^1\cos(x^2)\,dx+\int_1^\infty\cos(x^2)\,dx.$$ The first integral obviously converges since $|\cos(x^2)|\leq1$. For the second integral, we have $$\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x}\,x\cos(x^2)\,dx=\frac{\sin(x^2)}{2x}\bigg|_{x=1}^{x=\infty}+\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin(x^2)}{2x^2}\,dx.$$ This equality follows from integration by parts; the first term above is obviously convergent, while the integral can be bounded above, since $$\left|\frac{\sin(x^2)}{2x^2}\right|\leq\frac{1}{2x^2},$$and $\int x^{-2}\,dx$ converges as can be shown directly using the power rule for integration.

Comment: and finally, it is also good to mention that it converges to $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{8}}$ thanks to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral

Comment: @Peymanmohsenikiasari: Indeed! To determine the exact value the integral converges to resorts to using complex analysis (contour integration). I thought this might be a bit above a BC calculus class, so I didn't use it and instead chose to use elementary methods. There might be elementary methods to prove the exact value, but I'm not aware of any off the top of my head.

Comment: your answer was great and so helpful, thank you. I just mention that for "more information" for whoever visit this page in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Don't be deceived; although $\cos x^2$ oscillates, it does at a frequency which increases as $x,$ which makes the argument go to $+\infty$ as $x$ becomes arbitrarily large. Therefore, although it oscillates, it does so in such a way that it adds and subtracts sufficiently smaller and smaller areas, and does so faster than $x$ is running away, in order to converge.

---

I have given a heuristic explanation in the spirit of OP

Comment: Surely the frequency scales as $x$, not $x^2$, since it takes a $O(1/x)$ change in a large $x$ to increase $x^2$ by $2\pi$.

Comment: thanks, nice explanation! what a tricky and beautiful convergence problem it was.

Comment: @J.G. Sure, that's true. Thanks, I got carried away by the extremely loose way I was talking.

Answer (score 0):

The usual idea of a function decaying sufficiently fast for convergence of the improper integral does not apply to sign-changing functions. The reason for the convergence in this case is the highly oscillatory character of the function $\cos x^2$ at infinity. The positive and negative "areas" cancel each other and the integral converges.

Comment: I don't think that we can say "they cancel each other" that easily. why in cos x^2 "the areas cancel each other" but not in cos ln x? I think this needs better math proof.

Comment: I agree. That was just a rough explanation to make convergence plausible. To justify the claim, one should apply Dirichlet's or Abel's criteria, or a nice elementary argument like Clayton's.